# Tool to match mysql password encryption

Tags: mysql-5.5, linux

I've created a user ... but forgotten the password

```
mysql> create user 'blayo'@'%' identified by 'right';
```

Which Linux command line tool can **encrypt the password the same way mysql does ?**

```
mysql> select Password,User from mysql.user
------------------------------------------+-------+
*920018161824B14A1067A69626595E68CB8284CB | blayo |
```

...to be sure I use the right one

```
$ tool right
*920018161824B14A1067A69626595E68CB8284CB
```

Comment: Please [do not post the same question to multiple Stack Exchange sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-it-possible-to-post-questions-across-a-couple-of-the-sites-because-its-debata/64073#64073). [The Unix & Linux version](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44883/encrypt-a-password-the-same-way-mysql-does) has been answered as well, which is a waste of effort.

Comment: Forgot your password? [Google it!](http://www.google.com/search?q=920018161824B14A1067A69626595E68CB8284CB) Seriously: anytime a password is stored improperly (without [salt](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14025/why-is-using-salt-more-secure)), you're likely to be able to invert the hash with Google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use MySQL:

```
select password('foo');

PASSWORD('FOO')

*F3A2A51A9B0F2BE2468926B4132313728C250DBF
```

Comment: It's also super-handy how this stores your new password in clear text in both your bash history log and in your MySQL log, for easy retrieval later on.  ;-)

Answer (score 4):

MySql uses SHA1 to hash the password in the following way and then prefix's it with a star:

```
SHA1(SHA1(password));
```

The argument to the outer SHA1 must be the binary result of the inner hash for it to work properly.

**source:** MySQL source code and the following link:

http://palominodb.com/blog/2011/12/04/hashing-algorithm-mysql-password

Comment: This is a useful answer.  Just to say, the linked article has moved to https://www.pythian.com/blog/hashing-algorithm-in-mysql-password/.  It has a working example in SQL there which uses the `unhex` function to get the needed binary result.